# Is it Ok to pass jquery objects to different functions?

Tags: jquery

I am doing the following :

```
$(function() {
    var $txt = $("#text1");

    callMe($txt, $txt.val());                   


});

function callMe(t, vlue) {
    t.html(vlue)
}
```

I will be calling the callMe() function multiple times.

Is it Ok to do the way i have shown or is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no problem with passing jQuery objects around.

It will be much more efficient than re-running the selector each time - that's for sure.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery *is* JavaScript. And this is absolutely valid in JavaScript. You can even just pass the jQuery object an do this:

```
function callMe(t) {
    t.html(t.val());
}
```